# How to detect IE11 close event

Tags: javascript, button, internet-explorer-11, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I am now trying to detect only the event of the browser close button of IE11 in JavaScript.

I was able to detect the browser close button with the onbeforeunload event, but I also have trouble picking up other page transition events.

This code is I trying on it.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    alert('Sure you want to close ?');
}
```

Is there any good way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `addEventListener` syntax:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){
    alert('Sure you want to close ?');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply :)

I tried addEventListener, but this also picked up other page transition events.

In the past version of IE, if the value of event.clientY was minus, it could be detected as an operation to close the browser, but it could not be used in IE11...

Answer (score 0):

Actually the **onbeforeunload Event** will be fired when you close the browser/tab , refresh the page(or F5), submit a form, or jump to other pages..etc
AFAIK, there is not a perfect way to detect which operation exactly USER do.But for your question, i guess there are some html tag like

`<a href="abc.com">To ABC</a>`

that fired the **onbeforeunload Event** when they are clicked. If it is true, may be you can remove the Event when the HREF was active so that the Event would not be fired. 
Try codes blow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $("a").click(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        location.href = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
      });
  });
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
     return 'Sure you want to close ?';
  }
</script>
```

**Note that** this would not prevent the refresh opreation to fired the **onbeforeunload Event**, but i hope to provide some ideas for resolving your problem.